# Spring boot admin with containerized spring boot applications in rancher

Tags: docker, rancher, spring-boot-admin

My team and I are struggling to figure out a way to monitoring every instances of a dockerized service managed in a rancher.

**Our goal**

We would like to monitor every instance of our service in SBA in a readable manner (ex: having the container name as a service ID).

**What we have**

We are currently able to monitor every instance of a service. But those services are displayed with IP addresses.

```
http://10.42.41.109:8180/actuator/health
```

**What we tried**

We removed the `prefer-ip` property played with the following to avoid having the container name as domain in the URL:

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.management-url
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.health-url
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url 
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url
```

The last 2 did give us pretty URL, but we lost the ability to monitor each instance of a service (the last to register seems to be the one being monitored).

**Sooo...**

How can we retrieve health checks for each instance of a rancher managed service while keeping the monitoring human readable? Are we missing so magic option?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Which version of Rancher are you using?

Comment: @leodotcloud v1.6.13

Comment: Did you check the healthchecks available in Rancher? https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/health-checks/ Letting the infra handle the healthchecks for individual instances?

Comment: Those healthcheck give information about the container itself. We need to monitor what's inside the container.

Comment: You can specify the endpoint/URL of the app running inside the container which will indicate the health of the app. It's not just the container health.

Comment: I do want more than healthcheck. SBA provides access to JVM state which are not exposed through healthchecks. We can't dump heap neither through this.

Comment: Did you look into `rancher-metadata`? For example: `curl -H "Accept: application/json" rancher-metadata/latest/services/<your-service-name>/containers | jq .[].primary_ip` will fetch you the IP addresses of all of the containers of your service.